# Why a reply should include "did"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, answers

This is the dialogue which I heard in a TV show:

> The father asks: I heard your mission failed, Ranmaru.
>
> Ranmaru: Yes, it did fail.

Why doesn't he say **yes, it failed**?

Comment: Sometimes *did* and *do* are used in afirmative forms for emphasise. Here it's the same, it's  used for emphasising that the mission failed.

Comment: I decided to roll the question back to the original because the last edit seems to misunderstand the OP's intent, even though *I heard your mission* would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Avicenna You should expand that comment to an answer.